# Redux-form doesn't fire actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I have a Field

```
<Field name="SOME_ID"
           component={TestWrapper}
           options={this.getFridaIngredients()}
    />
```

The TestWrapper looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

class TestWrapper extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      textValue: this.props.input.value,
      selectValue: this.props.input.value
   }

    this.onSelectChange = this.onSelectChange.bind(this);
    this.onTextChange = this.onTextChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSelectChange(e) {
    if(e) {
      this.setState({
        textValue: e.value,
        selectValue: e.value
      })
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        textValue: '',
        selectValue: ''
      })
    }
  }

  onTextChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      textValue: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <TextField
           value={this.state.textValue}
           floatingLabelText="Some ID"
           onChange={this.onTextChange}
         />
       </div>
       <div className="col-md-6" style={{paddingTop: "29px"}}>
         <Select
           value={this.state.selectValue}
           options={this.props.options}
           placeholder="Search..."
           onChange={this.onSelectChange}
         />
       </div>
     </div>
   )
 }
}

export default TestWrapper;
```

The reason I have put the test wrapper in a component with a state for itself, is because I want to update the textfield whenever something is chosen from the SelectField, and I couldn't figure out to make it work when I did something like

```
<Field name="SOME_ID" component={SelectField} />
<Field name="SOME_ID.value" component={TextField} />
```

because the textfield wouldn't be set to the value on the initial rendering (i'm using the form for editing something).

So now my problem is that the SOME_ID field with the TestWrapper component doesn't fire any redux-form actions. When I change something or click something no FOCUS or CHANGE actions is fired. How can I make this work?

Comment: `TextField` prop `onChange` should be `this.props.input.onChange` or as you said, If you want to save the value in state, you can invoke redux-form's `onChange` from `onTextChange` as `this.props.input.onChange(e.target.value)`.

Comment: thanks. This is what I was forgetting